# How to decrypt nodejs "events.js:72" error?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a clean windows 8.1 box with latest node.js installed (0.10.29). I'm trying to make a simple web app:

```
npm install express-generator -g
express --css=compass test
cd test
npm install
npm start
```

After accessing web server, node exits with error. And i can't understand that error at all :(

[image]

First of all, what is this "events.js" file? Why no path? Is it a file in my app, some nodejs internal file or one of packages that was installed via `npm install`? Any way to figure this out?

Also, two lines after that seems to be an exception stack trace... But only two items in it? Why my app is not on stack trace? Why no full path for files? How can i figure out where they are locates and how my app is connected to this exception?

Any hints are welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`events.js` is a system module. It deals with events (just like it name states). The error actually isn't in this module, if you read through docs carefully you'll find out that:

> When an EventEmitter instance experiences an error, the typical action
>   is to emit an 'error' event. Error events are treated as a special
>   case in node. If there is no listener for it, then the default action
>   is to print a stack trace and exit the program.

So, something in your code emits `Error` event and since there is no listeners for that, EventEmitter (located in `events.js` file) throws an error.

As you can see from error message actual error is about try of launching something that not exists (code in your program tries to spawn child process but can't because of some reasons. I'm not using windows and don't know what your project does and how it works so you have to figure out reasons yourself). Tip: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/child_process.js#L1020

Your app is not on stack trace because spawning of a process is asynchronous. So, actual code that called `child_process.spawn` is no longer on the stack. It was...few iterations of event loop before but no longer there.
Sometimes modules like this might help: https://www.npmjs.org/package/superstack, https://www.npmjs.org/package/longjohn